# How to set values from Json to checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to retrieve input values from database to Crud menus that based on Bootstrap modals and datatables . With the text input there was no problem - i used this to retrieve :

```
 var data_row = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();

  $("#edit_campagne").val(data_row.campagne)
        .find('option[value=" + data_row.campagne +"]').attr('selected', 
   true);
```

But with the checkboxes it's more complicated - their values are saved as json - like this :

```
      {% for target in targets %} // I'm using TWIG 
         <div class="checkbox">
             <label>
               <input  class="animals_input" id = "{{ animals }}"
               // this generate id for each checkbox
                type="checkbox" value="0" name="animals_check[{{ animals 
               // this save values as Json -  {"dogs":"1","cats":"1"}
                }}]" >{{ animals  }}
              </label>
          </div>
       {% endfor %}
```

So when i retrive from DB the checkbox's values looks like this ( 1 is for checked) :

operation_target : "{"dogs":"1","cats":"1"}"

Now, i want to set this values to the checkboxes by their id So it will look like this :

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
         <input type="checkbox"
           class="animals_input" value="0" id="dogs"
           name="animals_check[]">Dogs // should be checked
    </label>
</div>
```

I'm looking for something like this :

```
   $(".checkbox").val(id from db)
        .find(id == id from db).prop('checked', true);
```

Here is an example - [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jI9ArQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Iterate through the keys in your json object
2. search by id
3. mark the box

Snippet (*Vanilla Javascript Soln*):

```js
var result = {
  "dogs": "1",
  "cats": "1"
}

for (var key in result) {
  if (result[key] === "1") {
    document.getElementById(key).checked = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="dogs">Dog<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="monkeys">Monkey<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cats">Cat<br>
```

Comment: Iceman , Rory McCrossan, Geo George - thanks for the quick response - all your suggestion works - but the check boxes data is not refreshing when passing from one page to another.... if in one page only one checkbox is checked - when i edit another row - the data is still appears....

Comment: ok, if you change the html then you will need to re run the function

Comment: tell me excatly how pagination is happening, is it client-side with ajax?

Comment: @RoyBarOn put the code in the `drawCallback` so that it gets called each time the table is redrawn. Should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Iceman - i just add all to drawCallback - but still the same problem - the check mark aren't refresh while all the data is... the check marks are added from on page to another....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142169/discussion-between-iceman-and-roybaron).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can loop through the keys of the object and set the checked state of the checkbox, like this:

```js
var obj = {
  "dogs": "1",
  "cats": "1",
  "ducks": "0"
};

for (var key in obj) {
  $('#' + key).prop('checked', obj[key] == "1");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="animals_input" value="0" id="dogs" name="animals_check[]">Dogs
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="animals_input" value="0" id="ducks" name="animals_check[]">Ducks
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="animals_input" value="0" id="cats" name="animals_check[]">Cats
  </label>
</div>
```

Also note that it would be *much* better practice to return a boolean value in the JSON instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  "dogs": "1",
  "cats": "1",
  "ducks": "0"
};
var checkboxsection=[];
$.each(obj,function(key,val){
  var checkboxtemp=' <label> '+
        '<input type="checkbox" class="animals_input" value="'+val+'" id="'+key+'" name="animals_check[]">'+key+
                '</label>';
     checkboxsection.push(checkboxtemp);         
});

$(".checkbox").html(checkboxsection.join(""));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">

</div>
```